# SignalR C# server and ASP.NET client

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I need that the client will send a message to the server and that the server will push a message to the client.

I'm trying to do a small example before I'll add it to the web app that I'm working on.

I read some tutorials that I found and saw some examples but I still can't make it work.

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(TestServer.Startup))]
namespace TestServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;


namespace TestServer
{
    [HubName("ServerHub")]
    class ServerHub : Hub
    {
        public void send(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.serverUpdate(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Client: 
I want to change Label2 text when a message from the server is pushed.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestClient.MainPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    </div>
    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script>
        var hub = $.connection.ServerHub;
        hub.client.serverUpdate = function (str) {
            $("#Label2").text(str);
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;

namespace TestClient
{
    public partial class MainPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/signalr");
            IHubProxy ClientHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ServerHub");
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientHub ch = new ClientHub();
            ch.sendUpdate("button clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to add something in the servers main that is related to Signalr?

In the client I'm not sure what url to put in the next line:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/signalr");
```

not sure that the way I sent the message to the server (after button click) is the right way.

Comment: I don't have that code anymore. Try to read the tutorial in the link below it includes different code examples.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in hub.client.serverUpdate method- the name of that method has to match the name of the method that you defined on the hub (send).  See the Getting Started tutorial here:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20